# Symbol Not Found - Sublime Text 3 -

Tags: java, ide

I have created a simple program that runs in Eclipse when I click on run. The class containing the main method ("HelloMain.java") instantiates a second class, "Hello.java" This works fine in Eclipse but I much prefer using Sublime Text 3 and when I run the same program in Sublime from the terminal I get a symbol not found error during instantiation.

I don't know why I am getting a symbol not found error, can you please comment if you have any ideas on why this is happening or if you have any ideas on how to fix this?

I've included a screenshot.

1. On the left you can see my program HelloMain.java
2. Below HelloMain.java you can see my second class, Hello.java
3. Below Hello.java you can see my terminal where I attempt to run my program

On the right you can see the same files

1. HelloMain.java
2. Below HelloMain.java is Hello.java
3. Below Hello.java is the terminal where I run the program with the exact same issue
4. and below that is the program functioning through the console

Please let me know if you have any questions or need clarification.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I personally can't tell you why this is happening, but I can tell you I wouldn't bother with either of these editors. Pick up Intellij IDEA. It's hands-down the best Java IDE available at the moment and won't give you problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of my files were not being compiled. I run my code through zsh, my terminal doesn't automatically compile all or any files unless it is specified. "javac" compiles a file.

This line of commands compiled and ran my java files in a folder.
The package and folder of the files I am running are both called model and I am in a subdirectory when running these commands.

"javac **/*.java && java model.HelloMain".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).